# Delete all files of a certain type from a TFS Team Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

We have migrated a large number of projects from SourceSafe to TFS 2012. We have used the [migration tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/867f310a-db30-4228-bbad-7b9af0089282) to successfully migrate all of the projects and their history. But have found that the SourceSafe specific project files, *.vssscc, have been left in place. We would like an easy way to remove all of these files.

Therefore **is there an easy way to delete all files of the type "vssscc" from a TFS Team Project**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the item spec is not a folder, recursive options apply to all files matching the given name (or wildcard).  So in this case:

```
tf delete /recursive *.vssscc
```

Should pend deletions for the files in question.